# Using Famo.us and Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, famo.us

I know this might sound a little crazy but here goes.

We have built an entire application in Ionic + angular. We have a big problem though, the performance of the page transitions and scroll is very poor. Obviously we will be optimizing but some of our transitions I don't think are going to work regardless of the efforts we make.

Last night in an effort to solve this problem I found Famo.us and liked what I saw. The problem is that we are on a tight deadline and we cannot afford to port the whole application to Famo.us and our developers have only just overcome the learning curve of Ionic and angular.

Is it possible to just use some parts of Famo.us but keep our Ionic core app. Essentially I would like to build the layout,  left/right horizontal scroll, up/down vertical scroll, menu, popups etc.. with Famo.us and leave the content using the Ionic framework?

Any help would be much appreciate, also if we can be pointed in the right directions a new library which is a marriage of both could be incredible, shallower learning curve and all the benefits of Ionics, build tools and easy use with Famo.us' excellent power and rendering!

Comment: Have you tested this Famo.us under a real device? Have you tried official Ionic forum for helping you with performance problems?

Comment: Not yet to either, that was my plan for today. Also one of the problems we are having is with a problem of using ionic slidebox and ionic content together, which is a known problem on the forum which I have yet to see addressed and we have yet to get to the point in our project where we can solve it. I was simply looking for other solutions to it.

Comment: there are some rules and use cases in ionic framework, how much data you are listing in a list view, also do you use collection-repeat for large datasets, do you have large size images etc., they are just a few example.

Comment: You needed to research that these two are going in different paths first [See Here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8186326)

Comment: Thank you for that post @talves. It sounds like they only think they are going down different paths? But Famo.us thinks they are looking to go down both?

Comment: Also just to note that we are not "breaking" any of the aforementioned rules @İlkerKorkut we just are seeing the inherent poorer performance of hybrid apps vs native and are looking to tighten things up.

Comment: @user1132726 right, and remember that there are **[some pitfalls](http://famo.us/guides/pitfalls)** to be aware of in famo.us that can help you make the decision to use it with another framework.

Comment: Your question didn't deserve a down vote. Famous has it's problems but might be a good fit. If your under a time crunch and your developers where just starting to feel like they are overcoming the learning curve don't switch. I would look more into iconic and ask for help with your performance problems like was suggested earlier. There is no magic library that fixes all the css html dom perf problems with a super minimal learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i'm dealing with something similar here (pushing Ionic slidebox to its limits, trying to lazy-load slides into the slidebox to improve performance, etc)

There's a good chance that if you switch to Famo.us for the UI of your app, you can reuse a substantial portion of your services, controllers, etc.  So to answer your question, **yes, you can keep parts of your ionic app and swap out other portions for Famo.us**.  Your 'content' wouldn't be 'Ionic' though - it would be Angular.

Make sure to use Famo.us+Angular here:
https://github.com/Famous/famous-angular

Another option you can try is to use Famo.us AND Ionic, using this generator to help you scaffold it out.  Personally I prefer just using one or the other though.

https://github.com/thaiat/generator-angular-famous-ionic

Good luck!